# Minimize the perimeter of a quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

Given ABCD is a square. E is a point on BC (not overlapping with B or C), and F is a point on CD (not overlapping with C or D).  $\angle$EAF=$45^o$, P is the mid point of EF.  AP=x, BE+DF=y.

**Question:** Are there two points M,N on AB and AD, respectively, so that quadrilateral MEFN has minimum perimeter? If yes, express this perimeter with x and y.

I started to explore the relationship among different segments and found y= EB+DF=EF, but do not know how to continue from this discovery.

[image]

Comment: Are $E,F$ constrained in any way?  Your diagram suggests they must lie on the sides $BC,CD$ respectively but your problem doesn't say so.

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks! You are right, I updated the question to point this out explicitly.

Comment: What tools are you allowed to use?  Offhand, this sounds like a calculus problem.  Are you expected to use calculus?

Comment: No calculus, just elementary geometry, not even trigonometry.

Comment: @BrightStar I still don't see that condition anywhere.  As far as your text goes, $E,F$ are never actually defined except for the two conditions $\angle EAF=45^\circ$ and $BE+DF=y$.  So there is not even the requirement $E,F$ on the plane.

Comment: @user10354138Sorry, I probably did something  wrong when editing last time.  Now it is updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a hint, I offer this figure:

[image]

Comment: @ David, excellent again, thanks!

Comment: @BrightStar indeed DavidK is so helpful. God bless DavidK